# Getting a count from Linq query with group by

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get a count by Month from the Linq query below? An error is returned telling me that "grp.INPUT_SOURCE" doesn't exist.

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-365);
var Total = UPDATE_TRANSACTIONS                     
  .Where(m => m.CREATE_DATE > yesterday)
  .Where(m => m.CREATE_DATE < DateTime.Today)
  .GroupBy(m=> new{m.CREATE_DATE.Value.Year, m.CREATE_DATE.Value.Month,m.CREATE_DATE.Value.Day, m.INPUT_SOURCE})
  .Select(grp => new {
                source = grp.INPUT_SOURCE,
                Count = grp.Count()
                });
Total.Dump();
```

Comment: For counts by month you have to group by month only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `source = grp.Key.INPUT_SOURCE,`
since that column is part of the Key